# .Net app under docker: significant delay in writing logs to the file shared with hosting system

Tags: docker, yaml, nlog

We have .net app that writes logs with help of Nlog logger to file source, logs are recorded all the time, every second. If you run it on Windows, no dockers, everything works fine: log records appear in the file immediately, but being deployed under our cluster of Linux dockers it takes from several minutes to hours to flash data into the file, which is shared with our host system. I can see data in the database, indicating that app ran successfully, but log file is not changed for a while. Having very little experience with dockers, not sure what it could be caused by, and even where to look at. I found yaml file that looks like this:

`mount -v -t cifs //10.153.1.61/apps/configs/stage/testApp/logs
          /logs/ -o credentials=/smb/smbcredentials;`

As it works fine without docker, I believe something is wrong in the way we create images and deploy dockers. Any ideas on where to direct the investigation is very appreciated.

Comment: So you are mounting your. log destination as a remote file system mount,  are you doing the same on Windows?  If not this might be your culprit,  network file shares are inherently slower compared to direct writes.  Could you mount your log volume as docker volume?  Also, is your app a Windows executable?  If so why are you running it on Linux cluster?  Windows has pretty good docker support these days.

Comment: @Vlad thank you for the hint.  "log volume as docker volume" did you mean replacing "//10.153.1.61/..." by direct file reference to the host drive? I think the reason we've been using network share is we want to have one single log file for all physical machines-hosts of the cluster. Not sure how otherwise we can make all dockers being deployed to different hosts store their logs to a single file.

Windows images are heavy, we decided to go Linux-based, but this is a totally different conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your see the slowness because you are trying to write your logs over the CIFS network share,  that's a lot of overhead.  You should consider using one of the commonly available distributed log handling solutions out there, such as [gray log](https://www.graylog.org/products/open-source), [ELK](https://www.elastic.co/) or Splunk(https://www.splunk.com/)

Looks like NLog has a [lot of](https://github.com/infobip/NLog.Targets.Gelf) integrations to choose from. There are very detailed step by step [tutorials](https://logit.io/sources/configure/nlog) available that explain the process in fine detail.

Using the centralized log collection not only will speed things up for you, it will let you query / combine logs from multiple containers and build graphs / dashboards giving more insight to you about the current status of your system.